# Array Mod + Color Ramp

Tags: texturing

I wanted to assign the colours from my ColorRamp to my objects array. I tried to "apply" the Array Mod but it did not change. It appears my Object Index is just set to "1". Where can I get the index number of my Array? It will likely work if I "apply" and "break apart" my array but I have other objects on my scene it would likely affect my "Object Index". I prefer not to apply my array and especially not to break apart my object. Any idea on how I can get the Array Index instead?

[image: Array Mod with Color Ramp]

This is closest to how I wanted it to look. I used Texture Coordinate to achieve this but what I wanted is to map each Array element into my colorRamp. Anyone knows how to do that?

[image: My temporary solution]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

if you don't want that "split color" in one cube, just adjust the z-rotation value a bit like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was editing my post when you posted that. Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for something that I could assign per array element if that's even possible.

Comment: Oh wow, gradient texture, why didn't I thought of that  been using the old arctan2 for most of my projects.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. It is - but then you have to apply your array modifier and do a separation of the objects (which you didn't want). But you could also give GN a try....which can do a lot more... ;)

Comment: Ah well, thanks for assuring me that it isn't possible without the caveats. I'll have to take your answer. Thanks for that 

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 9):

(The 'Object Index' output of the *Object Info* node does not mean the index of the object in an array. It refers to the 'Pass Index' number that can be found in the 'Object' tab > 'Relations' panel of the shaded object.)

If you want to get a number-per-element of an array into a shader tree, you can use the 'UV offset' field in the *Array* modifier:

[image]

Above, the UV's  U is offset by 1 per element of the array. This means element 0's U goes from 0->1, element 1's U goes from 1->2, and so on.

We can take the `Floor` of that in a shader tree:

[image]

This means element 0 has the number 0, element 1 has the number 1, and so on, to use for whatever per-element property you like. Here, the number has been divided by the number of elements, to give a 0-1 range for a *Color Ramp*.

Comment: Well done!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Worse than Chris'es and Robin's answers so I won't bother explaining and just post for completeness:

[image]

Comment: +1 for completeness‼️

Comment: +1 for the spectacular display of dashed arrows!

Answer (score 3):

and because you all forgot geometry nodes, which is a shame, here the geometry nodes solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate answer, this is what I end up using. Note that in my project, I'm facing the Y-axis. If you are doing it on the x-Axis, just swap separate XYZ to y, you will also need to play around with the parameters of the mapping part.

[image: My temporary solution]

On my project, the Y rotation adjustment is to make the colour start at the top instead of at the left.