# single mesh with multiple colors per part in array

Tags: modeling, materials, modifiers, shaders, shader-nodes

I've been wanting to make a model so when I make a single mesh into an array, each part of that array has a different color. The image below is some kind of example. For example, the first ribbon could be the main object and then the array repeats it 6 times below it.

What I'm asking is how can I make each array have a separate color so when I animate the original, the others animate the same and still keep their color. I've tried using the color ramp, but it won't let the colors stay on each array. So if the object curves, it will mix with the other colors.

I'm sure I'm using the wrong shader nodes, but that's all I can think of to show what issues I'm coming into. If I can do this without making separating all the arrays into their own object and make a material for each object, then that would really help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As well as the answers below, you might want to consider https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/233708/35559

Comment: I think here it would be distance from center, perhaps modified by the normal for more even distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geometry nodes can be used for such tasks:

[image]

Here is how it works:

First, an array can be created inside geonodes, such as this round one based on curve:

[image]

But you can also use Mesh island node and use regular array.

[image]

In this case the setup will look like this:

[image]

Then store index in custom attribute:

[image]

That can be used in material:

[image]

Point that, then you make an array using geometry nodes, you should set attribute in instances instead of points and get data in shader from instances instead of geomtery.